# How to reload image in the .kv file in Kivy and Python

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I try to reload an image in the .kv file, but I don't know, how this works. Can you help me?

On the internet are only articles how to reload the image, when it is in the .py file, but mine is in the .kv file.

This is the **main.py** file:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.clock import Clock


       

class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):

        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "BlueGray"
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1)
        return Builder.load_file("swiper.kv")
       


"""
class MyWebView(MDScreen):
    def Push(self):
"""
       

        

    
    




MainApp().run()
```

This is the swiper.kv file:

```
<MySwiper@MDSwiperItem>

    #FitImage:
    #    source: "images/aspen.png"
    #    radius: [20,]

MDScreen:
    

    MDSwiper:
        id: swiper
        size_hint_y: None
        height: root.height - dp(40)
        y: root.height - self.height - dp(20)

        on_swipe:
        on_pre_swipe:
        on_overswipe_right:
        on_overswipe_left:

        

        MySwiper:
            FitImage:
                source: "./images/screen.png"
                radius: [20,]
   
        MySwiper:
            FitImage:
                source: "images/bild2.png"
                radius: [20,]
        
        MySwiper:
            FitImage:
                source: "images/bild3.png"
                radius: [20,]
```

So how to update the

```
MySwiper:
            FitImage:
                source: "./images/screen.png"
                radius: [20,]
```

Images in a certain intervall?

Comment: You'll need to access the FitImage in the `.py` file either by assigning ids or through the built-in hierarchy (`object.children`) and then reload it.

Comment: @SanguineL How to do this?